# How to concatenate and uniquify lists in matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I've got a matlab structure that looks like

```
pointlesshorror

ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

      1   17   20

  [2,1] =

      2   17   18   21
...
  [16,1] =

     16   39   40

}
```

and another

```
misery = [1 2 3]
```

and I want to get the lists associated with each V

```
pointlesshorror(1) # 1 17 20
pointlesshorror(2) # 2 17 18 21
pointlesshorror(3) # 3 18 19 23
```

and put them together

```
[ 1 17 20 2 17 18 21 3 18 19 23 ]
```

and then uniquify them

```
unique([ 1 17 20 2 17 18 21 3 18 19 23 ])
```

to get at the end

```
[  1    2    3   17   18   19   20   21   23 ]
```

unfortunately, this has to be fast, and the only way to make matlab fast is to express everything as one-liners, and so I was wondering how to say:

```
(distinct (concat (map pointlesshorror misery)))
```

in matlab for these particular data structures.

And if anyone has any general tips for finding out the answers to these sort of problems, like what is the type of a variable, and what operations can I do on it, then they'd be most appreciated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have almost everything figured out already, apart from concatenating multiple entries of `pointlesshorror` at once.  Luckily this is simple: if you index a cell array with a vector, you get a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html;jsessionid=1710aec1b55c1123ecdeeabd0dec?s_tid=doc_12b), which are concatenated like this:

```
pointlessHorrorConcat = [ pointlessHorror{[ 1 2 3 ]} ];
```

So here is a full example:

```
pointlesshorror = { [ 1 17 20 ], [ 2 17 18 21 ], [ 16 39 60 ] }
misery = [ 1 2 3 ]
result = unique([ pointlesshorror{misery} ])
```

Comment: Dude, I literally want to have your babies. I even knew all that. It was just the {} that I was missing! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

The way you exposed your problem makes me think that `pointlesshorror` is a **cell** and not a **structure**, am I right?

If so:

```
pointlesshorror{1,1} = [1, 17, 20];
pointlesshorror{2,1} = [2, 17, 18, 21];
pointlesshorror{3,1} = [3, 18, 19, 23];

misery = [1, 2, 3];
```

Just do:

```
unique(horzcat(pointlesshorror{misery}));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is also a fine answer. I wish I could accept both. I saw the other one first. Thanks very much anyway!